# Code is correct although it compiles as 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: java, methods, compilation, syntax-error

Im trying to create the class isPalindrome and call upon StackArrayBased and QueueArrayBased although the compilation error indicates an error in my logic? I cant seem to find the problem with why it cannot find the two classes. First I gave my Palindrome code and following is the two classes I am trying to call.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class isPalindrome {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Word to check: ");

    String userInput = scan.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
    System.out.print(isPal(userInput)+" ");


}

public static boolean isPal(String str){
    QueueArrayBased aQueue = new QueueArrayBased();
    StackArrayBased aStack = new StackArrayBased();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        aQueue.enqueue(str.charAt(i));
        aStack.push(str.charAt(i));
    }

    //start to compare

    while(!aQueue.isEmpty()){
        if(aQueue.dequeue() != aStack.pop()){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

StackArrayBased

```
import ListReferenceBased.*;

public class StackArrayBased implements StackInterface
{
final int MAX_STACK = 50;  // maximum size of stack
private Object[] items;
private int top, count;

public StackArrayBased()
{
items = new Object[MAX_STACK];
top = -1;
count = 0;
}  // end default constructor

public boolean isEmpty()
{
return (top < 0);
}  // end isEmpty

public boolean isFull()
{
return (top == MAX_STACK-1);
}  // end isFull

public void push(Object newItem) throws StackException
{
if (!isFull()) {
  items[++top] = newItem;
  count++;
} else {
  throw new StackException("StackException on " + "push: stack full");
}  // end if
}  // end push

public void popAll()
{
items = new Object[MAX_STACK];
top = -1;
count = 0;
}  // end popAll

public Object pop() throws StackException
{
if (!isEmpty()) {
    count--;
  return items[top--];
} else {
  throw new StackException("StackException on " + "pop: stack empty");
}  // end if
}  // end pop

public Object peek() throws StackException
{
if (!isEmpty()) {
  return items[top];
} else {
  throw new StackException("Stack exception on " + "peek - stack empty");
}  // end if
}  // end peek

public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    for( int i=0; i < count; i++){
    st.append(items[top+i]+" ");
}
    return st.toString();
}
}  // end StackArrayBased
```

QueueArrayBased

```
public class QueueArrayBased implements QueueInterface
{
private final int MAX_QUEUE = 50; // maximum size of queue
private Object[] items;
private int front, back, count;

public QueueArrayBased()
{
items = new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
front = 0;
back = MAX_QUEUE-1;
count = 0;
}  // end default constructor

// queue operations:
public boolean isEmpty()
{
return count==0;
}  // end isEmpty

public boolean isFull()
{
return count==MAX_QUEUE;
}  // end isFull

public void enqueue(Object newItem) throws QueueException
{
if (!isFull()) {
  back = (back+1)%MAX_QUEUE;
  items[back] = newItem;
  ++count;
} else {
  throw new QueueException("QueueException on enqueue: Queue full");
}  // end if
}  // end enqueue

public Object dequeue() throws QueueException
{
if (!isEmpty()) {
  // queue is not empty; remove front
  Object queueFront = items[front];
  front = (front+1)%MAX_QUEUE;
  --count;
  return queueFront;
} else {
  throw new QueueException("QueueException on dequeue: Queue empty");
}   // end if
}  // end dequeue

public void dequeueAll()
{
items = new Object[MAX_QUEUE];
front = 0;
back = MAX_QUEUE-1;
count = 0;
}  // end dequeueAll

public Object peek() throws QueueException
{
if (!isEmpty()) {
  // queue is not empty; retrieve front
  return items[front];
} else {
  throw new QueueException("Queue exception on peek: Queue empty");
}  // end if
}  // end peek


public String toString()
{
 StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
         st.append(items[front+i]+" ");
     }
 return st.toString();
} // end of toString
```

``  } // end QueueArrayBased

Comment: What and where is the error?

Comment: Are the files in the same package and the same folder?

Comment: please post the exception stack trace

Comment: You can just do `return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString().equals(str);`

Comment: Could sound like a missing import statement or a build problem. Hard to tell from the source code, though. You may want to do a minimal example ([see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and include directory/folder structure. Also tell us which IDE you are using since it may be a problem specific to it.

Comment: If I move the isPalindrome.java to the StackArrayBased folder then it cannot find my QueueArrayBased and vice versa. I tried putting the StackArrayBased into the QueueArrayBased folder to hopefully fix it but it did not. I have had a issue with this in the past as my understanding of pathways is clearly not solid. I know its something tiny and that is what bothers me

Comment: If I save isPalindrome to the Stack folder then i get this error and vice versa if I save it into the Queue folder then I get the same errors but with Stack                         [isPalindrome.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  QueueArrayBased aQueue = new QueueArrayBased();
  ^
  symbol:   class QueueArrayBased
  location: class isPalindrome
isPalindrome.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  QueueArrayBased aQueue = new QueueArrayBased();
                               ^
  symbol:   class QueueArrayBased
  location: class isPalindrome
2 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1]

Comment: I am using TextPad

Comment: You should consider using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans. And it looks like you need to import those classes into the isPalindrome class.

Comment: @johnhopkins how would I do that in Textpad? Also whats the advantages of those cause I would love something a bit more lenient on advanced things like this that im unsure of

Comment: Since you're using Textpad, I'm assuming you're also using the command prompt to compile. I'm not too familiar with that process when the classes are in different folders. You probably need to add package statements to the top of every class, and then `import packagename.classname` in classes that need it. The benefit of IDEs is that it handles packages, imports, and compiling for you, along with offering auto-complete and pointing out errors and suggesting fixes.